# How can I troubleshoot an iTunes install problem?

Tags: itunes, install, macos

I'm having a hard time trying to install iTunes on my Windows 7.

After reading some sites like [this](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1926), [this](http://www.apple.com/support/itunes/troubleshooting/) or [this](http://support.apple.com/kb/ts1717), I can`t go further then trying to install, and failing after few seconds, without any meaningful error message.

In some blog I have even found the the command-line switch

> iTunes64Setup.exe /l*v c:\log.txt

to generate a log, but it doesn't give me any useful information. And since my wife is getting bored with her iThings that can't be connected to the iTunes, I ask you...

... where can I find more troubleshoot information? Is there some e-mail at Apple that would analyze my .log and help me ?

*Edit:*

- there is no Apple folder in Program Files or Program Files (x86)
- there is no Apple software installed in the computer

*Edit 2:*

The end of the log says:

> Property(C): INSTALL_ASUW = 1
>
> Property(C): INSTALL_BONJOUR = 1
>
> === Log parado: 25/09/2013  21:26:57 ===
>
> MSI (c) (6C:F8) [21:26:57:117]: Note: 1: 1708
>
> MSI (c) (6C:F8) [21:26:57:117]: Transforming table Error.
>
> MSI (c) (6C:F8) [21:26:57:117]: Transforming table Error.
>
> MSI (c) (6C:F8) [21:26:57:117]: Produto: iTunes -- Falha na instalação.
>
> MSI (c) (6C:F8) [21:26:57:117]: O Windows Installer instalou o produto. Nome do Produto: iTunes. Versão do Produto: 11.1.0.126. Idioma do Produto: 1046. Fabricante: Apple Inc.. Status de erro ou êxito da instalação: 1603.
>
> MSI (c) (6C:F8) [21:26:57:133]: Grabbed execution mutex.
>
> MSI (c) (6C:F8) [21:26:57:133]: Cleaning up uninstalled install packages, if any exist
>
> MSI (c) (6C:F8) [21:26:57:133]: MainEngineThread is returning 1603
>
> === Verbose logging stopped: 25/09/2013  21:26:57 ===

In a free translation: error or exit status of the instalation: 1603

Comment: What is the message you get ? or the log ? maybe we can see something in it to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a long time, problem solved. Was the admin user of the Windows 7 that was corrupted, somehow. Created a new one and everything works.

This way this question got a kind of off-topic, so I'll flag it to be deleted in few days.

Comment: It's a question about using Apple software. It's on-topic here.